# Is AWS EMR suited for an HA spark direct streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a apache spark direct streaming application in AWS EMR.
The application receives and sends data to AWS kinesis and needs to be running the whole time.

If course if a core node is killed, it stops. But it should self-heal when the core node is replaced.

Now I noticed: When I kill one of the core nodes (simulating a problem), it is replaced by AWS EMR. But the application stops working (no output is send to kinesis anymore) and in also does not continue working unless I restart it.

What I get in the logs is:

```
ERROR YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 1 on ip-10-1-10-100.eu-central-1.compute.internal: Slave lost
```

Which is expected. But then I get:

```
20/11/02 13:15:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 193.1 in stage 373.0 (TID 37583, ip-10-1-10-225.eu-central-1.compute.internal, executor 2): FetchFailed(null, shuffleId=186, mapIndex=-1, mapId=-1, reduceId=193, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 186
```

These are just warnings, still the application does not produce any output anymore.

So I stop the application and start it again. Now it produces output again.

My question: Is AWS EMR suited for a self-healing application, like the one I need? Or am I using the wrong tool?
If yes, how do I get my spark application to continue after a core node is replaced?

Comment: Well it is running Spark with YARN so it should

Answer (score 0):

Its recommended to use On-Demand for CORE instances
And at the same time use TASK instance to leverage SPOT instances.

Have a look

- [Amazon Emr - What is the need of Task nodes when we have Core nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41519400/7857701)
- [AWS DOC on Master, Core, and Task Nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-master-core-task-nodes.html)